# Puppeteer tests don't run after implementing percy io

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I installed Percy, wrote tests and decided to start, but I get this error: "percy" is not internal or external command, executable program, or batch file.

My .json:

```
{
  "name": "pptr-visual",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Regression testing with puppeteer",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test:percy": "percy exec -- jest -i ' ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@percy/puppeteer": "^2.0.2",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-image-snapshot": "^6.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "puppeteer": "^19.11.1"
  }
}
```

Scripts what i tryed:

```
"test:percy": "percy exec -- jest -i ' ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js'"
"test:percy": "percy exec -- jest -i  ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js"
"test:percy": "percy exec -- jest -i 'tap'  ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js"
"test:percy": "percy exec -- jest ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js"
"test:percy": "percy exec -- jest node ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js"
"test:percy": "percy exec -- node ./tests-snapshots/__tests__/percy.test.js"
```

and their variations
*I checked the path is correct